# Bootstrap 4 : Float custom-checkbox to right of the text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card attribute filter-panel" data-type="select" data-id="1">
  <div class="card-header">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down   pull-right"></i>
    <span class="card-title">color</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" style="padding: 0px; padding-top: 15px">
    <ul class="filter-ul">
      <li>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck1" value="1">
          <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck1">red</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck2" value="2">
          <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck2">blue</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck3" value="3">
          <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck3">green</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Current position**

[image]

I want the `checkboxes` to float to the right of the text, I have tried `float:right` obviously didn't work.

how can i float them to the right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `postition: absolute` to move your boxes to right side and content to left side, hope this heck is work great.

You can play with `right` CSS property to get exact result you want.

```css
.custom-control-label::before ,.custom-control-label::after {
    right: 0;
}

label span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 21px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card attribute filter-panel" data-type="select" data-id="1">
       <div class="card-header">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down   pull-right"></i>
          <span class="card-title">color</span>
       </div>
       <div class="card-body" style="padding: 0px; padding-top: 15px">
          <ul class="filter-ul">
             <li>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">
                   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck1" value="1">
                   <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck1"><span>red</span></label>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">
                   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck2" value="2">
                   <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck2"><span>blue</span></label>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">
                   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck3" value="3">
                   <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck3"><span>green</span></label>
                </div>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `custom-control-label` class has already `position: absolute;` so you can remove that one

Comment: Since you answer is not buggy like mine when we check boxes, I'm gonna delete mine and go for yours.

Comment: so nice of you :D

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card attribute filter-panel" data-type="select" data-id="1">
   <div class="card-header">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down   pull-right"></i>
      <span class="card-title">color</span>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body" style="padding: 0px; padding-top: 15px">
      <ul class="filter-ul">
         <li>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">

               <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck1">red</label>
                 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck1" value="1" style="float:right">
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">

               <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck2">blue</label>
               <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck2" value="2"style="float:right">
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">

               <label class="custom-control-label " for="customCheck3">green</label>
                 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox " id="customCheck3" value="3"style="float:right">
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Check this code.I set the checkboxes to the right side of text. I think that's what your problem was.I hope this will help you :)

Comment: that not working, in simple HTML its work fine but with bootstrap its not work atall

Comment: @NishargShah Are you sure?Can you please copy and paste my code in online bootstrap editor first and then check.I checked it and its working fine

Comment: @NishargShah yes I saw,Sorry that was my mistake that I solved question in codesnippet without adding bootstrap but in bootstrap edittor as per the link which I provided,Its giving same result.Anyway I will find some better way to solve this problem.Thank you

Comment: No problem, appreciate you find problem, I removed downvote